# perturbation of a signal with normal noise in C++

Tags: c++, noise, normal-distribution

How can I perturb a signal like for exemple sin(x) with a gaussian noise?

I need something like this:

```
#include <math>
#include <lib with gaussian noise>
int main{
 float *a[Dim]
 for(int i=0;i<Dim;i++)
  a[i]=sim[i/10]+noise;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++.11, you can use [`std::normal_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution). The code would look something like this:

```
#include <random>
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
    std::normal_distribution<> d;
    float *a[Dim]

    for(int i=0;i<Dim;i++) {
        float noise = d(gen);
        a[i]=sim[i/10]+noise;
    }
}
```